# How to install SimpleCV on mac OS 10.8.1

Tags: python, macos, simplecv

So I have been trying to install SimpleCV for some time now. I was finally able to install pygame, but now I have ran into a new error. I have used pip, easy_install, and cloned the SimpleCV github repository to try to install SimpleCV, but I get this error from all:

```
           ImportError: No module named scipy.ndimage
```

If it is helpful, this is the whole error message:

```
           Traceback (most recent call last):
           File "/usr/local/bin/simplecv", line 8, in <module>
           load_entry_point('SimpleCV==1.3', 'console_scripts', 'simplecv')()
           File"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resource               s.py", line 318, in load_entry_point
           return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
           File"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2221, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
          File"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
          entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
          File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/SimpleCV/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
          from SimpleCV.base import *
          File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/SimpleCV/base.py", line 22, in    <module>
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
          ImportError: No module named scipy.ndimage
```

I am sorry if there is a simple solution to this, I have been trying and searching for solutions for well over an hour with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have SciPy installed to use SimpleCV.

Take a look on this site: http://penandpants.com/2012/02/24/install-python/

You may also need to install opencv, you can use homebrew for that.

Answer (score 0):

On osx 10.9 I did

```
sudo pip install scipy
```

It worked.